# Loading Custom Font In LWC from Static Resources

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css, static-resources, font

Im So confused with this, I have tried a lot of ways but none of them seems to work for me.

The resource is named "IBMPlexSerif", its file is a .zip named "IBMPlexSerif", When I double-click the zip, there is a folder inside it with the same name "IBMPlexSerif", that folder contains a bunch of .ttf files:

- IBMPlexSerif-Medium
- IBMPlexSerif-Bold
- IBMPlexSerif-Light
- IBMPlexSerif-Thin

... all of them .ttf

I'm specifically interested in IBMPlexSerif-Light.ttf one. That's the one I want to use in my LWC

tag

this is the way I'm trying to reference it in my css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "IBMPlexSerif";
   src: url("/resource/IBMPlexSerif/IBMPlexSerif/IBMPlexSerif-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
 }

 p {
    font-family: "IBMPlexSerif";
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
```

But the LWC is not taking it, it just puts times new roman or whatever standard font it is.

What Am I doing Wrong?

I dont know if I am missing something in the .js using loader function, or if I just dont need that. Or if I should not be using double quotes to reference the resource path.

This LWC is supposed to be embedded in a community page, Does that have anything to do with the issue?

Also this is the error logged in console that the component throws:

....my.site.com/resource/IBMPlexSerif/IBMPlexSerif/IBMPlexSerif-Light.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 503 (Service Unavailable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really are 99% already there. Just cut out the second "IBMPlexSerif" from the url...

`"/resource/IBMPlexSerif/IBMPlexSerif-Light.ttf"`

... and it will work - in communities too. Depending on your users, you might want to adjust system permissions of profiles or cache control (see for example [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_vf_static_resources.htm&release=220&type=5)). The name of the original file is of no importance anymore.

(To my knowledge, the 503 status would indicate that there's another problem though - on the side of Salesforce. You should simply have got a 404 using the url that you state in your text. This might have hampered your testing.)